# When to call function that calculates width of elements?

Tags: angular, angular5

In my angular project, I have two tables.
One of the table is loaded with data from a service, and on ngOnInit this data is returned.

I am calculating the header columns width and applying it to another table.
And I call this.resizeColumn() function on :

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
this.resizeColumns();    
 }
```

And also on:

```
 @HostListener('window:resize')
 onResize() {   
this.resizeColumns();
}
```

The problem is, that when the page is opened for the first time, the widths that are calculated are not applied yet.
Once I resize the window, then the two headers match.
The idea is that whenever the table width changes, this function to be called as well.
After what event or lifecycle hook should I call resizeColumn, so that initially both tables have the same column width ?

Comment: Although doesn’t seem exactly a duplicate to me, have a look at this question and the comments for the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729202/change-element-width-dynamically-on-angular-5

Comment: Thank you . I did read into it and just tried the same code that was in the accepted answer. But that does not resolve my issue.
Because as soon as I resize the window, then the table header gets the values.
I've been trying to implement something like this :

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/pu4q1931/3/) But as you can see the fiddle does not have that issue, because it has JS. I dont know how to do the same in angular so that as soon as the program is run,it takes those widths.

Comment: In that case let’s try to figure out the problem. So when you open the page, in the code, are the widths already calculated correctly but then not applying them or they are not available until you do the resize?

Comment: Thank you so much!The widths are there, but the issue is :
When I refresh the page ( or open for the first time), the table is first empty, and then gets filled.
So the header gets the widths that the table has in the beginning.
Now , after the table has been filled, the widths of the source column have obvously changed.
But those changed aren't applied to the target header until I resize the window.
Is there a way to listen to when the table is resized to call the function ?
So that whenever the original table changes width, the calculating function is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of property binding to link the column widths of the two tables, as shown in [**this plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/NuRo3WBwAwwmdpsrwwOM?p=preview). In my example, the column widths in the top table are increased at regular intervals, and the bottom table column widths follow with property binding.

```
<table>
  <tr #table1Row>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
    <td>Column 3</td>
  <tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td [style.width.px]="getColWidth(table1Row, 0)">Column 1</td>
    <td [style.width.px]="getColWidth(table1Row, 1)">Column 2</td>
    <td [style.width.px]="getColWidth(table1Row, 2)">Column 3</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

```
// Get the column width from Table 1
public getColWidth(row: HTMLTableRowElement, index: number): number {
  return row.cells[index].offsetWidth;
}
```

**Update:**

If you need to make the change asynchronous (to avoid an Angular exception), you can try the following code (implemented in **[this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OGDSNX3CLAPH3gBFnVI2)**). It calls `setTimeout` to get the new width after the current execution cycle.

```
private colWidths: Array<number> = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

public getColWidth(row: HTMLTableRowElement, index: number): number {
  let width = row.cells[index].offsetWidth;
  if (Math.abs(this.colWidths[index] - width) > 0.001) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.colWidths[index] = width;
    }, 0);
  }
  return this.colWidths[index];
}
```

Comment: But I am changing the width of the columns with property binding.  The issue is that the original column header gets its width based off the content.
And when you first start off the app, the table for a split second has no data ( the target column gets the column width of the original columns)
and then the table gets the data, the original columns expand in width. The target column remains the same.
What I'm trying to understand is how to have the target columns to change their width whenever the original table columns have changed.
I am using @ViewChildren to get the native element too

Comment: I changed my function to this earlier: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729202/change-element-width-dynamically-on-angular-5) 
And I'm not sure how to make the changes of the table to fire the calculations and get the widths.

Comment: In my example, the widths in Table 2 are linked to the actual widths in Table 1 (measured with `offsetWidth`). If the widths in Table 1 change to adapt to their content, the widths in Table 2 will follow with the help of property binding. I adapted [my Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NuRo3WBwAwwmdpsrwwOM?p=preview) to show the result for a content change in Table 1. Please note that, with this property binding, you don't need to monitor an event, and you don't have to know when the widths in the first table change. Angular change detection mechanism takes care of that for you.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!
 But I have a hard time following something:
So you use getColWidth(index:number) to get the width of the column of the table ?
And then you bind that to the column in your table using property binding ?
this.row.cells[index].offsetWidth, how doe this line know what width to take ? 
or is `this.row`, the rows that are being returned by the get row() ?
So what I would need to do is get the rows with ViewChildren, and I'd have their width in offsetWidth?
I apologize, I just want to make sure I understand clearly.

Comment: I simplified my answer and [my plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NuRo3WBwAwwmdpsrwwOM?p=preview) by passing the table reference variable directly to `getColWidth()` in the template markup. Note: the template reference variable `table1Row` is also used with `@ViewChild()` in the code of the plunker but only to increase the size of the column in the example. You would not need to do that in your code.

Comment: Thank you, but I still have the same issue, except that now when I resize the table, I have to click anywhere, in order for the other columns to get their width. It doesn't change dynamically as one changes. :|

Comment: `Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '90'. Current value: '85'.` 
Whenever the table is resized

Comment: Difficult to know what is going on without seeing the code. Can you put it in a plunker? Even if it does not run or compile, I could inspect it to get a better overall view.

Comment: Yes [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/GWxtoNtGXyS4uAUPLUDc?p=preview)
I have a dropdown that filters the table. And when I click on  a filter on the actual program, the table gets smaller in width. Should I also put the filters?
And it shows the error that Expression Has changed after it was checked.

Comment: In your plunker, there are two header sections in the same table. And the property binding is between these two headers. Is your markup really like that? Your original question was about having the same column widths in two tables.

Comment: No. I will update it sorry.
I have two tables. One table only has the header ( that needs to get the widths ) and the other table has the data and the normal header. Wait.

Comment: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/pRKf1yWTJjgJFzuPPfRT?p=preview)
I updated it here. This it the actual code. I had misplaced when I copied it.

Comment: There should be a way to solve the error mentioned above but it is not simple. It is caused by the fact that the "source" table is below the one that you want to adapt. Just for the sake of debugging, you can swap the two tables in your markup and see if the code works.

Comment: I did that, and I still have the same error when filtering.
It's because it gets the width of the columns.
And then when I filter,as I said, the width changes ( because some columns get smaller).
And it's when I get the error again , saying expression changed after it was checked.
I thought property binding would mean whenever the source column changed, the target would also change cuz angular detects changes.
But now it throws error.

Comment: Hmmm. Not easy. :-) Can you put the filtering code in the plunker?

Comment: Can you upvote the question so I have enough reputation to move this to chat ?
And I can explain the code in detail ?
Or do you want me to write the pipe that filters it and everything in the plunker ? :) I can do that too.

Comment: I already upvoted the question. :-) You can put everything useful in the plunker. Please note that I will be a little busy in the next 2 hours but I will come back here periodically.

Comment: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/2WzMwvPF670B5RGZSXo2?p=preview)
i only added the pipe as a comment, since the code doesn't compile anyway.
But the point is :
When I have all colors : I can have Red, Green, Blue..and the width of that column is based off the largest text.
So if I filter for Red.
Then that column will only display Red, so its width will be smaller.
Now that's where I get the error. Because when I filter and the width of the column changes, the error in the console says that Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value 100px, current value 88px.

Comment: I added a variation of the code in my answer, to get the new column width asynchronously (see [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/OGDSNX3CLAPH3gBFnVI2)). That may solve the exception that you get from Angular. The `prevWidths` array should have at least as many items as the number of columns in your tables.

Comment: One more thing: in my plunker, I set the padding of the cells to zero. If `padding-left` and/or `padding-right` are not zero, the column widths will not match exactly because `offsetWidth` includes the padding and `style.width` does not. If you want to keep the padding, you should make the correction for it in `getColWidth`.

Comment: Thank you . That did solve the errors issue, but even though its timeout is 0, this way it is kinda slow to apply the changes for some reason.
But this definitely helped and i will mark it as correct :) !! Thank you so much!